# IdentityServer 4 user-info endpoints returns forbidden status

Tags: c#, identityserver4

i just got started in identityserver4 and couldn't figure out why the user-info endpoint is returning a forbidden status

```
    public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
        return new List<Client>
        {
             new Client
             {
               ClientId = "client1",
               AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
               ClientSecrets =
               {
                   new Secret("secret".Sha256())
               },
               AllowedScopes =
               {
                     "api1",
                     IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                     IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
               },
               IncludeJwtId = true,
               RequireConsent = false,
               AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
               AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,

             }
        };
    }.
```

my users :

```
    public static List<TestUser> GetUsers()
    {
        return new List<TestUser>
        {
            new TestUser
            {
              SubjectId = "1",
              Username = "admin",
              Password = "admin",
              Claims = new List<Claim>
              {
                  new Claim("Name", "test")
              }
            }
        };
    }
```

i'm requesting this way :

```
        var disco = DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:44327").Result;
        var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, "mvc", "secret");
        var tokenResponse = tokenClient.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync("api1","admin","admin").Result;
        if (tokenResponse.IsError)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.Error);
            return;
        }
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);

        var res =  client.GetAsync(disco.UserInfoEndpoint).Result;
        var claims = res.Content;
```

why i'm getting a forbidden status code in the userinfo endpoint ? 
any help is appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check your client configuration. In the `GetClients()` you have a `ClientId = "client1"` and then in the token client build-up you have `var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, "mvc", "secret");`.

Your `clientId` is not correct. Where is this `mvc` coming from?

Answer (score 0):

the forbidden response can also be the result of the incorrect scope , in case you want to get some information about the  user from the userinfo endpoint you must include OpenId scope in the used token  , when you decode your token you must have the openid scope in it like in the picture [openid scope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dKRa.png)